# Get Parent Theme Author Name

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme, wp-get-theme

I want to to get the Author name of the Parent theme.

I can get the theme name using wp_get_theme() to get the theme object of the current (child) theme. From this I can get the parent theme name.

Next I think I need to get the object of the parent theme, but unsure how best to approach this. Here is my code so far:

```
$style_parent_theme = wp_get_theme();
$style_parent_theme_dir = $style_parent_theme->get( 'Template' );
$style_parent_theme_name = wp_get_theme($parent_theme_dir);
$style_parent_theme_author = $style_parent_theme_name->get( 'Author' );

if ($style_parent_theme_author == "WooThemes") {
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for all the help which pointed me in the right direction. In the end I used the following:

```
$style_parent_theme = wp_get_theme(get_template());
$style_parent_theme_author = $style_parent_theme->get( 'Author' );
```

I use get_template() to recover the folder name of the parent theme.

wp_get_theme then get's the theme object.

Once we have that we can manipulate the object to get the author name.

Comment: You can make it one liner too: `$style_parent_theme_author = wp_get_theme( get_template() )->get( 'Author' );`

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for getting the name of the parent theme and stumbled over this post.

I think the best solution is not mentioned here:

```
wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Author' );
```

or what I needed:

```
wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Name' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 of your code reads:

`$style_parent_theme_name = wp_get_theme($parent_theme_dir);`

it should be:

`$style_parent_theme_name = wp_get_theme($style_parent_theme_dir);`

otherwise the code is correct.

Comment: Note: two variable names do not reflect their real meaning: `$style_parent_theme` better be `$style_current_theme` and `$style_parent_theme_name` better be `$style_parent_theme`

Answer (score 1):

You can get this value about the child theme. At first get your child theme date. The simplest way is the function `wp_get_theme()`, see [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme) for the parameters and more information. You get a object with all relevant information about the current theme. In step two check, if is a child theme and then get his parent information, like the follow source.

```
// Current WP_Theme object.
// Get this data via hook or class WP_Theme
// As wrapper, simple to sue is the function wp_get_theme()
$theme_data    = wp_get_theme();
$is_child      = $this->is_child( $theme_data );

if ( $is_child ) {
    $parent_name = $theme_data->parent()->Name;
}
```

The method `is_child` is simple:

```
function is_child( $theme_data ) {
    // For limitation of empty() write in var
    $parent = $theme_data->parent();
    if ( ! empty( $parent ) ) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
  <?php
  $my_theme = wp_get_theme('parentThemeName');
  echo $my_theme->get( 'Author' );
  ?>
```

Comment: It does not explain why his code returns incorrect author of parent's theme.

Answer (score 0):

simple function

```
function show_theme_author(){

    $theme = wp_get_theme();

    return $theme->get('Author');

}
```

Comment: this shows the version - the question was about getting the author name

Comment: @raison  pasted wrong function  , fixed